# How to login into website using RESTAPI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest

Sorry for asking very basic question. First time I am using REST API. I tried to get answer to this question on google. But I am unable to get any such.

I need to login into a website using password based authentication using REST API and Python. I dont want to use selenium or some other tools for this purpose due to company policy.

```
Website Name : https://www.test.com
Username : admin
Password : test@123
```

Any clue/idea on proceding further please?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about the authentication? Do you need to send a simple `POST` Request to the url with the Username and Password? Is it using HTTP Basic Authentication?

Comment: @Maurice I need to use simple password based / HTTP basic authentication. Just I want to login into this website for doing further actions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Google chrome REST client extension or postman.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try use the POSTMAN as you said.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to issue requests and authenticate yourself using HTTP Basic Authentication, this example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) should help:

> Use of Basic HTTP Authentication:
>
> ```
> import urllib.request
>
> # Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
> auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
> auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
>                           uri='https://mahler:8092/site-updates.py',
>                           user='klem',
>                           passwd='kadidd!ehopper')
> opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
> # ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
> urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
> urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/login.html')
> ```

For more complex usage scenarios I suggest using the [httplib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httplib2). A great introduction to that is [here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/http-web-services.html).